# How to get time passed since last event in /dev/input/eventX?

Tags: bash

I only have 1 device connected to my Raspberry Pi - an optical touch screen.
I want to shutdown the display after the user hasn't clicked/touched anything for more than an hour.
I'd use the `vcgencmd display_power 0` command when that happens.

I tried looking at the "modify" time with commands like `date -r event0` and stat `event0`, but the modify time does not change when I use the touchscreen.
I'm looking for (preferrably) a `bash` solution to check when was the last time a user used the touchscreen.

Comment: Maybe you could use tail and diff in your bash script. Save `tail event0` somewhere and then compare it to current tail output. If there is difference save latest tail output. If you save it to a file, you have new modify time for checking. If they are the same, see if time since last modify time is too long. You can run that in an endless loop and check every n seconds.

Comment: That's a nice idea. But I tried looking at event0 file with `head`, `tail`, and `cat` - none work (the commands never complete) ... I tried running them with sudo permissions as well. Not sure if this is a problem for another question.